# Change project icons in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, icons, netbeans-8

is it possible to change icons for project view in NetBeans? Class, enum and interfaces have all crazy similar icons so its purpose to distinguish its file function in project is gone.

Update: https://pasteboard.co/HwQw5Zn.png <-

Comment: Update your post with a screen shot to show an example of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was previously raised with NetBeans 7 as a bug, and the outcome of that is the icons you see now! See NetBeans [Bug 225049 - Different icons for classes and interfaces (and possibly abstract classes, enums and annotations)](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=225049) for the details.

The **class** and **enum** icons in the **Projects** panel certainly still look very similar to me, though individual eyesight, monitor quality and screen resolution are also relevant.

Unfortunately there is no way for the user to customize these icons; they are internal to NetBeans. It's also unfortunate that there is no way to adjust the size of the icons. Even if you increase the size of the font used by NetBeans (by setting **--font_size** in **netbeans.conf**) the size of the icons is not increased.

The situation is doubly frustrating because the three icons used to represent a **class**, an **enum** and an **interface** in the **Navigator** panel are much more distinguishable than the rectangular "paper" icons for the corresponding files in the **Projects** panel:

[image: icons]

The situation is unchanged in the recent release of NetBeans 9. It is very unlikely that this will ever be addressed in NetBeans 8.2, so I can only suggest that you [create a new bug for NetBeans 9](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-1071?filter=allopenissues).